# 3D AR Objects are shaking in Vuforia

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

I have create multiple image targets using Vuforia and Unity software. When Playing AR camera, the four objects seem to be unstable and shaking a lot. Any advise please.

Answer (score 0):

Few things you can do:

1. Vuforia Setting, Camera Device Mode: MODE_OPTIMIZE_QUALITY (by default, it use low resolution webcam texture)
2. Make sure you have good lighting condition(most important)
3. Make sure you have 5 stars marker
4. Make sure your physical world has enough complexity if you use extended tracking feature
5. What's your testing/target devices?

Those are based on my exhibition setup experience.

Comment: I am fairly new to Unity and Vuforia, And I am trying to build a demo for a school project. I am currently testing using Sony Xperia Phone XZ2 and a simple webcam. I was wondering if this could something related to my 3D models. However I had same shaking effect when I used simple Cube from Unity. Could you please explain what is extended tracking and how to control it.

Comment: extended tracking is a feature in Vuforia Settings. It requires ARCore or ARKit supported devices, for marker less tracking. Do you have any video which can demonstrate your issue? AR is great, but it still has limitations, especially lighting conditions.